# Getting File from <input type ="file"> in C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

i need to get the filename from  my input id is Announcement_PIC, but it always return null when i try to get the filename. below is my code:

Front side:

```
<input type="file" runat="server" class="textboxTabsFiles" ID="Announcement_PIC"/>
```

Backend:
i've already included the below in the partical class:

```
protected System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputFile File1;
protected System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputButton Submit1;
```

This is how i'm currently getting my filename

```
string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Announcement_PIC.PostedFile.FileName).ToString();
```

Edit: my file upload is placed inside a JQuery tabs and using the asp fileupload it also has problem getting the file name, thus i tried using input file

Comment: on which event do you have this code ? why aren't you using Asp's FileUploader

Comment: In the `RSS` feed, this question's title creates a file up-loader box like the one here:  [File Upload](http://www.javascript-coder.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/file-upload.png). Pretty nifty.

Comment: Are you performing an async postback or a full postback?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using webforms take a look on [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Have you remembered a `enctype='multipart/form-data'` on the form-tag?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use:

```
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
```

That will allow you to access .HasFile & also perform .SaveAs